# Обособление в деепричастных оборотах с частицей только

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому правилу здесь ставится или не ставится запятая?..

*Удовлетворить эти требования возможно (,) только обладая всей полнотой информации о последних достижениях во всех областях науки и техники.*

Или здесь тесная связь деепричастия со сказуемым?.. Или какое-то другое правило?..

Comment: Само предложение содержит грамматическую ошибку. Хороший пример для задания  № 8 ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

*Удовлетворить эти требования возможно, **только обладая** всей полнотой информации о последних достижениях во всех областях науки и техники.*

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=113

3. Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы **только, лишь,** интонационно не отделяется от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но запятая перед ним обычно ставится: *Понять это произведение можно, **только учитывая** условия его создания; Выучить иностранный язык можно, **лишь** постоянно занимаясь им.* Но (при **тесном слиянии** оборота со сказуемым): Они встретились только будучи уже взрослыми.

Примечание. Здесь в принципе невозможно тесное слияние сказуемого с деепричастным оборотом ввиду его **распространенности.**

Comment: Спасибо большое...